# How to do sum of a sequential data in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am stuck in a query where I have to do a sum of a column (`distance`) when a column (`ignition`) is 1 separated by ignition is 0.

[image]

For example answer: 208 and 12. Until now what I have tried is I have find when the sequence has break but unable to move forward

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 2147483647
        rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.DeviceTimestamp),
        p.TrackedPointID,
        p.Ignition
    FROM 
        trackedpoints p 
    ORDER BY 
        p.DeviceTimestamp
)
SELECT
    cte.TrackedPointID,
    prev.Ignition PreviousValue,
    CTE.Ignition,
    nex.Ignition NextValue
FROM 
    CTE
LEFT JOIN 
    CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
LEFT JOIN 
    CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
WHERE
    prev.Ignition = 0 
    AND cte.Ignition = 1
GO
```

Comment: Please edit your question to replace that image of sample data with DDL + DML statements, and add desired results.

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify the groups of adjacent values.  One method is a difference of row numbers:

```
select min(DeviceTimestamp), max(DeviceTimestamp), sum(distance)
from (select tp.*,
             row_number() over (order by DeviceTimestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by ignition order by DeviceTimestamp) as seqnum_i,
      from trackedpoints tp
     ) tp
where ignition = 1
group by (seqnum - seqnum_i);
```

It is a little tricky to explain why the difference of row numbers identifies adjacent values that are the same.  However, if you run the subquery and stare at the results, you can see how the difference defines these groups.

Also note that the `where` clause needs to go into the outer query.  Otherwise, the "0" values that separate the adjacent groups of "1"s will not be visible.